# Do mutiple checked across various radio buttons in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing an application that display 2 graphs and contain radio buttons to change the time interval.
What i'm trying to do is, for example, if i select monthly in the 2nd set of radio buttons the first set should also have that option check.

```
<div class="panel-radio-buttons">
    <form id="SettingMixRadioButtonsGroup1">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient"  
                           ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetDay()'>Daily</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="2" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient2"
                           ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetWeek()' >Weekly</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="3" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient3"
                           ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetMonth()'>Monthly</label>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="panel-radio-buttons">
    <form id="SettingMixRadioButtonsGroup2">
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient4"  
                           ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetDay()'>Daily</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="2" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient5"
                           ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetWeek()'  ng-checked="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame2" >Weekly</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="radio1" value="3" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient6"
                           ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetMonth()'>Monthly</label>
    </form>
</div>
```

I've tried to checked using the following code in JS:

```
$scope.SetDay= function(){
    document.getElementById("SettingMixRadioButtonsGroup1").child[0].checked = true;
    document.getElementById("SettingMixRadioButtonsGroup2").child[0].checked = true;
};
```

But It won't perform the check on the child element... if i use the parent it works fine but its not a very scalable solution

Comment: You should use .. getElementById(... .prop('checked', true); to get the status and what comes to relations of your radiobuttons, this link might help you to see how you can call and chain parents to see which ones are checked: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26907052/8703483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates a handler for the `change` event for the radio buttons. It selects all radio buttons under `panel-radio-buttons` which have the same `value` attribute and sets their `checked` property to that of the element which triggered the event.

```js
$("input[type=radio][name=radio1]").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).attr("value");
  var radio = $(".panel-radio-buttons input[type=radio][name=radio1][value=" + val + "]");
  radio.prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-radio-buttons">
  <form id="SettingMixRadioButtonsGroup1">
    <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient" ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetDay()'>Daily</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="2" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient2" ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetWeek()'>Weekly</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="3" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient3" ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetMonth()'>Monthly</label>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="panel-radio-buttons">
  <form id="SettingMixRadioButtonsGroup2">
    <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient4" ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetDay()'>Daily</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="2" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient5" ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetWeek()' ng-checked="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame2">Weekly</label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
            <input type="radio" name="radio1" value="3" id="BtnEnrollmentsInpatient6" ng-model="togglePefsBifsTimeFrame" ng-change='SetMonth()'>Monthly</label>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you very much